# Which of the following is true for the definite integrals shown above?

Tags: calculus, integration, gre-exam

$$J = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^4}\,dx$$
$$K = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+x^4}\,dx$$
$$L = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^8}\,dx$$

Which of the following is true for the definite integrals shown above?

(A) $J<L<1<K$

(B) $J<L<K<1$

(C) $L<J<1<K$

(D) $L<J<K<1$

(E) $L<1<J<K$

What is the smartest way of solving this question other than solving the integrals as this question must take from me at most 2.5 minutes during the examination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing, any inequality among the radicands holds also for the integrals. On $[0,1]$ we have $0 \leq x^8 \leq x^4 \leq 1.$ So $$1-x^4 \leq 1-x^8 \leq 1 \leq 1+x^4.$$

Edit: And obviously none of these is equality everywhere on the interval! Thus the strict inequalities in the given statement.

Comment: I do not understand why " any inequality among the radicands holds also for the integrals" ?

Comment: @MathLover I'm just observing that if $0 \leq f \leq g$ on $[a,b],$ then $\sqrt{f} \leq \sqrt{g}$ on $[a,b],$ and so $\int_a^b \sqrt{f(x)}dx \leq \int_a^b \sqrt{g(x)}dx.$

Comment: what do you mean by "And obviously none of these is equality everywhere on the interval"?

Comment: @MathLover I wrote my argument with weak inequalities (for no particular reason -- you can just work on the open interval if you prefer), then noticed that the original post has strict ones. But my weak inequalities are certainly not equality everywhere (or *almost everywhere*, if you know what that means), so the weak inequality of integrals is actually strict.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}L-J&=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^8}dx-\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^4}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{1-x^8}-\sqrt{1-x^4}\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{1-x^8}\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{1-x^4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^8}+\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^4(1-x^4)}{\sqrt{1-x^8}+\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx>0
\end{align}$

Therefore $L>J$ and $(C),(D),(E)$ are false.

$\begin{align} K-1&=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^4}dx-\int_0^1 1 dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{1+x^4}-1\right)dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{1+x^4}\right)^2-1^2}{\sqrt{1+x^4}+1}dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^4}{\sqrt{1+x^4}+1}dx>0\\
\end{align}$

Therefore $K>1$ and $(B)$ is false.

Therefore $(A)$ is true

I have supposed the question has an unique answer.
Otherwise to be sure $(A)$ is the good answer it remains to prove that $L<1$. Same method can be used to prove this.